# css breakpoints for Honor 6X phone

Tags: css

The Huawei Honor 6X phone has a screen size of 1080 x 1920px (and a density of 404ppi) according to the specs.

The css density is calculated at x3, so the responsive breakpoints in css should be 360px (1080/3) for vertical orientation and 640px (1920/3) for horizontal.

Yet in practice the vertical calculation functions as expected at 360px but the real horizontal breakpoint turns out to be 592px (592 x 3 = 1776). Why should this be? Have I misunderstood the way this is calculated?

Comment: You can use @media and screen (max-width="767px"){
/*place your code here*/
}

Comment: That discrepancy seems common with phones. I don't know why. I assumed it was accounting for margins or frame around the screen.